# How to check Which Version Number of Google Chrome is Installed on Mac System

Tags: macos, cocoa, google-chrome

I am trying to find the Version Number of Google Chrome installed on the Mac Machine. ?

How can I find the Version Number.

Please Answer with some Snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same way you get the version of any other application: [Create an NSBundle object for that application's application bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithURL%3a), then [ask it for its value for](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/objectForInfoDictionaryKey%3a) the Info.plist key [`kCFBundleVersionKey`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFBundleVersionKey). The value of that key is an NSString or NSNumber containing the app's version.

To create the NSBundle object, you'll need to find where Chrome is installed:

- If Chrome is running, then there is an NSRunningApplication for it. Use [the `runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunningApplication/runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier%3a), then, from each running application, get its `bundleURL` and create an NSBundle from that. You'll probably want to find the greatest version number (latest running version).
- If Chrome is not running, then `runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:` will return an empty array, and you should move on to trying to find the bundle on disk. Ask [the shared NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSWorkspace/sharedWorkspace) for the [absolute path to a bundle with Chrome's bundle identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier%3a), then [create an NSBundle with that](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithPath%3a).